# jQuery Show image in a div with a third click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function () {
    var i = 0;
    $('.class').click(i=i+1)
        if(i=3) {
            $('.class2').css('display','block');
        }
    }
```

This code does not work, Please help me.

Comment: The code has some formatting problems and/or missing curly brackets. Please fix those. Next, here you only define a function, you don't call it. So what's the expected behaviour and what's the actual one? One can guess the answers, but please do edit your post so that it gets high quality (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `if(i=3)` `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be :

```
$(function() { //ready function
    var i = 0;

    $('.class').click(function(){ //Attach click event to '.class'
        i=i+1; //Or i++;

        if(i===3) { //Use triple equal '===' for comparaison
            $('.class2').css('display','block');
        }
    })
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your click event outside the function, and then track the 3rd click.  You should also use a comparison operator instead of assignment.  Of course, all of this should be wrapped in document ready.

```
var i = 0;
$('.class').on('click', function() {
   i = i + 1;
   if(i === 3) {
       $('.class2').css('display','block');
   }
});
```

[Here is a Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/228t3hyq/).